# Asking Normalization about 2NF and 3NF

Tags: database, model, database-normalization

I need help for **2nf** and **3nf**

So I already figured out the *UNF* for my table, which is:

```
UNF: orderID, productID, quantity, orderStatus, orderDate, address, transactionID, customerID
```

Here's my **1nf**:

Table List of order consists of: `orderID, orderStatus, orderDate`

Table product consists of: `productID, quantity`

Table Transaction consists of: `transactionID, address, customerID`

I have problems finding the 2nf and 3nf. Any ideas?

Comment: To normalize a relation in Second or Third Normal Form it is essentially to know the functional dependencies that hold among its attributes. From the simple list of attributes nothing can be said with certainty. So, to help you, we need the functional dependencies.

Comment: hm.. what do you mean by functional dependecies? is it my table 's relationship? im sorry for my bad english. @Renzo

Comment: For a definition and some examples, you can see for instance the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency), or any good book on databases (there is a lot of them).

Comment: If you don't know what a functional dependency is then you don't know what normalization is. What do *you* mean by normalization? What reference(s) were you given? Please give what you understand it to mean, and where the first "problem" you "have" with it.